# NHibernate Object References to null in Where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

I have an ISession.Queryover code block. In where clause, there is a problem as shown below

```
var receipts= ISession.QueryOver(() => receipt)
    .Where(Restrictions.Le(
                Projections.Property(() => receipt.SentDate), 
                receipt.LastDate), 
           null) //object references to null
```

In general I have a table called receipt and I am trying to get datas in case their LastDate is equal to their SentDate.
I guess it is because I used same object for comparing.

I need to compare those 2 property which belong to same entity.How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you add a little more of the code, to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MickyD unfortunately no :/

Comment: Us there a reason you don’t use the query syntax which is regular LINQ? `var receipts = session.Query<Receipt>().Where(x => receipt.SentDate <= x.LastDate)` with `<Receipt>` being the type you want to query.

Comment: yes @ckuri, after implementing this, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you're using a mix of two different types of syntax.

Perhaps you can use something like this instead:

```
var receipts = 
      ISession.QueryOver(() => receipt)
              .Where(x => x.LastDate >= x.SentDate)
```

Comment: .Where(x => x.LastDate >= x.SentDate)
this line fixed the problem! Thanks for helping :)
Can you add this line to your answer? I will accept it and meybe some other people can get help from this

Comment: Ah, that's even shorter and better. :) Glad it put you on the right track. I've updated my answer, as you suggested.